# Re-size select box in jquery mobile ?

Tags: jquery, css

i want to smaller the select box in jquery mobile ,,

here is my my code :

```
 <td >
    <select id="nlocation1" name="nlocation1" data-mini ="true" />

    <?php 
        $sql1="select * from apps.xx_fa_location_mob order by description";
        $res= oci_parse($link, $sql1);
         oci_execute($res);

         while ($row = oci_fetch_array($res))
         {
        $str  = $row[2] ;
        $str_id = $row[1];
        echo "<option value = '$str_id' >$str</option>";

        }



?>

            </select></td>
```

i have used this css style but it does nothing

```
   <style type="text/css">
#nlocation1.ui-controlgroup-controls{
width: 50% !important;
}

</style>
```

what should i do to small the select box ,, please any help  would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appli css to .ui-select

```
.ui-select{width: 50% !important;}
```

and if you want to apply to specific select box

```
<td id="myFirstSelect" >
<select id="nlocation1" name="nlocation1" data-mini ="true" />
```

and add css as

```
#myFirstSelect .ui-select{width: 50% !important;}
```